# ClassCastException with deferred binding only in compiled mode + Chrome / Safari - Firefox works

Tags: java, gwt

I have a very strange error, occurring only in chrome and safari.

I get an UmbrellaException when calling GWT.Create(foo.class); (Deferred binding)

Anyone any idea?

I figuerd out that java script throws an umbrella exception with the following javascript:

```
function entry_0(jsFunction){
  return function(){
    try {
      return entry0(jsFunction, this, arguments);
    }
     catch (e) {
      throw e;
Uncaught com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Exception caught: null
    }
  }
  ;
}
```

In gwt its on the specific java code

```
IAmsPresenterFactory factory = (IAmsPresenterFactory) GWT.create(IReflectiveAmsFactory.class);
```

where IReflectiveAmsFactory is to create instances by class name (string)... ([class for name gwt](http://samuelschmid.blogspot.ch/2012/05/using-generator-for-generic-class.html))

```
public class IReflectiveAmsFactory implements IAmsFactoryWrapper {

}

public interface IAmsPresenterFactory {
    IDynamicAmsPresenter newInstance(String className, AmsClientFactory clientfactory, String id);
}

    <generate-with class="ch.zhaw.ams.server.ams.AmsPresenterGenerator">
        <when-type-assignable class="ch.zhaw.ams.client.ams.IAmsFactoryWrapper" />
    </generate-with>
```

Full code snippet:

```
Request<IModuleBaseProxy> req = clientfactory.getRequestFactory().moduleRequest().findModuleBase(modtoken);
req.fire(new Receiver<IModuleBaseProxy>() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(IModuleBaseProxy response) {
    System.out.println("found");
    if (response != null) {
        ---> HERE
        IAmsPresenterFactory factory = (IAmsPresenterFactory) GWT
        ---> ERROR                          .create(IReflectiveAmsFactory.class);
        String clazz = response.getConfigSite();
        AmsClientFactory apcf = null;
        if (clientfactory == null) {
            apcf = new AmsClientFactory();
        } else {
            apcf = clientfactory;
        }
        IDynamicAmsPresenter p = factory.newInstance(clazz, apcf, modtoken);

        HasWidgets content = view.getContent();
        // ContentPresenter contentPresenter = new
        // ContentPresenter(apcf, p, new
        // ContentView(modtoken));
        p.go(content);
    }
}
});
```

My Generator Class:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;    
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.Generator;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorContext;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.TreeLogger;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.NotFoundException;
import com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle;
import com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ClassSourceFileComposerFactory;
import com.google.gwt.user.rebind.SourceWriter;

public class AmsPresenterGenerator extends Generator {

    @Override
    public String generate(TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context, String typeName)
            throws UnableToCompleteException {

        logger.log(TreeLogger.INFO, "Generating source for " + typeName, null);
        TypeOracle typeOracle = context.getTypeOracle();
        JClassType clazz = typeOracle.findType(typeName);

        if (clazz == null) {
            logger.log(TreeLogger.ERROR, "Unable to find metadata for type '" + typeName + "'", null);
            throw new UnableToCompleteException();

        }

        try {
            logger.log(TreeLogger.INFO, "Generating source for " + clazz.getQualifiedSourceName(), null);
            JClassType reflectableType = typeOracle.getType("ch.zhaw.ams.client.ams.IDynamicAmsPresenter");

            SourceWriter sourceWriter = getSourceWriter(clazz, context, logger);

            if (sourceWriter != null) {
                sourceWriter.println("public " + reflectableType.getQualifiedSourceName()
                        + " newInstance(String className, AmsClientFactory clientfactory, String id) {");

                JClassType[] types = typeOracle.getTypes();

                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                    // System.out.println(""+types[i].getName());
                    if (types[i].isInterface() == null && types[i].isAssignableTo(reflectableType)) {
                        System.out.println("Done:" + types[i].getName());
                        if (count == 0) {
                            sourceWriter.println("   if(\"" + types[i].getQualifiedSourceName()
                                    + "\".equals(className)) {" + " return new " + types[i].getQualifiedSourceName()
                                    + "(clientfactory, id);" + "}");

                        } else {

                            sourceWriter.println("   else if(\"" + types[i].getQualifiedSourceName()
                                    + "\".equals(className)) {" + " return new " + types[i].getQualifiedSourceName()
                                    + "(clientfactory, id);" + "}");

                        }

                        count++;

                    }

                }

                sourceWriter.println("return null;");
                sourceWriter.println("}");
                sourceWriter.commit(logger);
                logger.log(TreeLogger.INFO, "Done Generating source for " + clazz.getName(), null);

                return clazz.getQualifiedSourceName() + "Wrapper";

            }

        } catch (NotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    public SourceWriter getSourceWriter(JClassType classType, GeneratorContext context, TreeLogger logger) {

        String packageName = classType.getPackage().getName();
        String simpleName = classType.getSimpleSourceName() + "Wrapper";
        ClassSourceFileComposerFactory composer = new ClassSourceFileComposerFactory(packageName, simpleName);

        composer.addImplementedInterface("ch.zhaw.ams.client.ams.IAmsPresenterFactory");
        PrintWriter printWriter = context.tryCreate(logger, packageName, simpleName);

        if (printWriter == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            SourceWriter sw = composer.createSourceWriter(context, printWriter);
            return sw;
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: We need the generator. Have you tried using the `-XdisableCastChecking` compiler option as suggested in the original article?

Comment: Posting the rest of the stack trace would be good too - `Exception caught: null` could mean a null pointer, or an exception about some null arg, or an assertion without a message, and since it is going off in the generator, it could be a bug there, or it could be some other rule that doesn't make sense to dev mode. Also try compiling, and sharing that log, with either its success or failure.

Comment: I posted a link (class for name gwt) there its exact the generator i use. I have no stacktrace because its only apearing in compiled mode and not in the debug mode.

Comment: Yes i tried it - the article is wrote by me - it used to work for one year and now it doesnt work any more - i have no idea why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with upgrading to GWT 2.5.1

Having Compiler Arguments

-XdisableCastChecking

And VM Arguments

-Xmx512m -Xss16M

Answer (score -1):

I think it is problem with Deferred Binding. it is very much browser dependent. As I know if you want to write any browser dependent or locale dependent code like GUI change, then you have to create instance of it instead of use different Deferred Binding.

As you say it works in firefox because it might  compile with firefox and generating firefox versions of code at compile time. and loaded by a particular firefox during bootstrapping at runtime and not for others client.

`Deferred binding is a feature of the GWT compiler that works by generating many versions of code at compile time, only one of which needs to be loaded by a particular client during bootstrapping at runtime.`

`Mostly internationalized applications or GWT RPC calls you will be using deferred binding`

For more information check the GWT page on Deferred binding:

[Coding Basics - Deferred Binding](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred)